# Monit script not working to restart service

Tags: linux, bash, shell, monitoring, monit

This is my first post so please be patient with me!

I have tried to create script that checks if service is unreachable (http error code), then Monit should restart program (Preview Service). Monit is run as user "spark".

This is phantomjs-check.sh code:

```
#!/bin/bash
# source: /opt/monit/bin/phantomjs-check.sh

url="localhost:9001/preview/phantomjs"

response=$(curl -sL -w "%{http_code}\\n" $url | grep 200)

if [ "$response" = "}200" ]
then
        echo "-= Toimii!!!! =-"
        exit 1
else
        echo "-= RiKKi!!!! =-"
        exit 0
fi
[root@s-preview-1 bin]#
```

If I manually kill previewservice and run that script I get exit code of 0 which is how that should work.

In Monit I have following conf:

```
check program phantomjs with path "/opt/monit/bin/phantomjs-check.sh"
if status = 0 then exec "/opt/monit/bin/testi.sh"
```

Currently I added some logging to it and this is test.sh code:

```
#!/bin/sh
# source: /opt/monit/bin/testi.sh

############# Added this for loggin purposes ############
#########################################################

dt=$(date '+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S');
echo Testi.sh run at $dt >> /tmp/testi.txt

# Original part of the script
sudo bash /opt/previewservice/preview-service.sh start
```

In /etc/sudoers file I have line:

```
spark ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /opt/previewservice/preview-service.sh
```

This command works from cli and it starts/restarts previewservice. I can run "testi.sh" script manually as spark `[spark@s-preview-1 bin]$ ./testi.sh` and it works as intended, but even Monit gets info that service is down it doesn't start.

```
$ cat /tmp/testi.txt
    Testi.sh run at 05/01/2018 10:30:04
    Testi.sh run at 05/01/2018 10:31:04
    Testi.sh run at 05/01/2018 10:31:26
```

$ `cat /tmp/previews.txt` (This line was created by preview-service.sh start script so it has been run.

```
File created 05/01/2018 09:26:44
********************************
Preview-service.sh run at 05/01/2018 10:31:26
```

`tail -f -n 1000 /opt/monit/logfile` shows following

```
[EET Jan  5 10:29:04] error    : 'phantomjs' '/opt/monit/bin/phantomjs-check.sh' failed with exit status (0) -- -= RiKKi!!!! =-
[EET Jan  5 10:29:04] info     : 'phantomjs' exec: /opt/monit/bin/testi.sh
[EET Jan  5 10:30:04] error    : 'phantomjs' '/opt/monit/bin/phantomjs-check.sh' failed with exit status (0) -- -= RiKKi!!!! =-
[EET Jan  5 10:30:04] info     : 'phantomjs' exec: /opt/monit/bin/testi.sh
[EET Jan  5 10:31:04] error    : 'phantomjs' '/opt/monit/bin/phantomjs-check.sh' failed with exit status (0) -- -= RiKKi!!!! =-
[EET Jan  5 10:31:04] info     : 'phantomjs' exec: /opt/monit/bin/testi.sh
[EET Jan  5 10:32:04] error    : 'phantomjs' '/opt/monit/bin/phantomjs-check.sh' failed with exit status (0) -- -= RiKKi!!!! =-
[EET Jan  5 10:32:04] info     : 'phantomjs' exec: /opt/monit/bin/testi.sh
[EET Jan  5 10:33:04] info     : 'phantomjs' status succeeded
```

And the last status succeeded comes when I run that testi.sh script as spark without sudoing.

Any tips what I should try next? I appreciate all the help I can get!

- [Monit Previewservice status - Failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLQQL.png)
- [Manually as spark it works.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXBzu.png)

Comment: In general it is not a good idea to have `sudo` inside a scripts. Run the script itself with `sudo` instead. Also, try to change the line `sudo bash /opt/previewservice/preview-service.sh start` to `sudo /opt/previewservice/preview-service.sh start`. You are running bash with `sudo` instead of the script.

Comment: I changed that sudo bash to sudo but no luck with that either.

Comment: why do you use `#!/bin/sh` and not `#!/bin/bash` in the script `testi.sh`. These interpreters may happen to be different depending on the distribution you use.

Comment: I have tested like 100 and 1 different scripts and adjusted them a bit and tested. I'm not "true" Linux admin (at least not yet) and I have mostly worked with Ubuntu but nowadays CentOS is our primary OS.

Can that affect so I can run them with user spark but when Monit runs script it can not? (Monit daemon is started as spark too).

Answer (score 0):

Monit is usually running at *root* user. Is it your case ? If yes, you probably don't need the sudo part.

After regarding you script working outside of Monit but not from Monit, Monit is having its own *PATH* environment variable which is very small. It is recommended to write full path to your script/binairies as:

```
/usr/bin/sudo /bin/bash /opt/previewservice/preview-service.sh start
```

Comment: I was taken to another task and was not able to check this further more. Although, Monit was not running as root and I changed it to use root.

Will edit this when I get back to that a bit later.